# Are there any downsides to using double-slashes in URLs?

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, uri, url-routing

I've written my own MVC framework in PHP, which uses urls in the format of:

`/controller/method/param1/param2/param...`

I've made it so that "default" methods can be ignored (by default `index()`), so this results in URLs like `/controller//param1/param2/param...`. For example, a URL of: `/view//panel-glide/3` will call `index('panel-glide', 3)` in the `view` controller.

This works fine and dandy, but I'm concerned that search engines or some older browsers might freak out when they see the double slashes, as I don't think I've actually seem them ever be used before.

Is anyone aware of any issues I might come across by using this?

Comment: Just a side note: why not enforce a rigid structure of controller/method?param1=value1&param2=value2...? Seems much more RPC-like to me.

Comment: @LiorCohen Drupal for instance accepts a format like you suggest but rewrites the url to the OP's format.  It's possible he just omitted that that is being done behind the scenes.

Comment: My primary concern is flexibility rather than strict structural enforcements. And query string parameters are still accessible with my input class (e.g. `$this->input->get('param`')` would return `value1`). I want to allow URI segments to be parsed as method parameters (like in CodeIgniter) for ease of use and nicer urls (like `/blog/post/hello-world-foo-bar-baz`)

Comment: Search engine issue: Apache Solr's JSON parser cannot handle a double slash; their extension adding comments to JSON grammar is broken and the slashes will comment out the closing quote of a string

Comment: @Potatoswatter I think you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @pyrokinetiq Using double-slashes as you're doing is perfectly ok according to the multiple URL and URI standards. BUT, using two slashes where only was meant is a very common error, so there are a lot of applications that normalize multiple contiguous slashes in path to just one slash. This **will cause errors for you too**. For example, a lot of crawlers will fail to crawl your site correctly, since normalizing multiple slashes is a very common practice.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is an existing answer on WebMasters that discusses the [dangers of having two slashes](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/8381). It discusses Apache a lot, but the ideas should be applicable generally.

In essence, I don't think it is recommended. `/foo/bar` and `/foo//bar` really should be **two completely different paths**. Each slash is significant, and attempts at circumventing that standardization are bound to come back to bite you.

As is mentioned in the answer, there's also a **very real** danger of relative paths failing. Some browsers will *correctly* figure that a relative path `../../fizz` from `/foo/bar//baz` is `/foo/bar/fizz`, while others will treat the double slash as a single one, and opt for `/foo/fizz`.

Plus, I think it looks funny.

Comment: I agree.  As a developer it looks funny.  As a user it looks funny.  Actually, if I bookmarked that url and the link was broken, I would expect removing the extra / to fix it.  And tbh, a change in the code might make that happen.

Comment: @nomaD Just rewrite the extra / out of there.

Comment: In my case `/foo/bar` and `/foo//bar` ARE two completely different paths. `/foo/bar` will be loading the `bar()` method/action of the `foo` controller, `/foo//bar` will be loading `index('bar')` of the `foo` controller.

Comment: I agree. A user typing a URL like that is likely to feel confused.

Comment: @nomaD: There's more to it than just aesthetics. See my edit. Is there a reason why you don't want to make the `/foo/index` an explicit URL?

Comment: Ah that's the sort of answer I was looking for, I wanted to know if there's any actual issues with my implementation rather than whether or now it would work (which it does) :).

And `/foo/index` is an explicit URL, I just thought being able to exclude `/index` would be a lot nicer aesthetically, so you could load the default method (`index()`) of `foo` by simply going to `/foo`.

Comment: @nomaD: If your routing engine is clever enough, there's also the option of having `/foo` call the default `index()` method on the `foo` controller, and then for more complex URLs, like `/foo/bar/baz`, it would first try to find a `bar()` method and, only when that fails, it will try to call the `index()` method using `bar` and `baz` as arguments. Makes it a bit more complex, and there's probably a slight performance tradeoff, but might achieve what you're describing. Of course, there's also the danger of `bar` being both a method _and_ an argument to `index()` at different times...

Comment: @nomaD: So, actually, you might _not_ want to try that. :]

Answer (score 3):

Apache treats multiple slashes as a single slash. This affects things such as `RewriteRules`, e.g. if you have a rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ /user.php?id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

That will catch links such as `user/nomaD/500` but it will not catch `user//500` since it treats that as `user/500`

<strike>So in other words, I don't think your setup will work since it will treat `param1` as `method` and shift all the parameters left, unless they are of a specific type.</strike> I guess this doesn't affect your specific case, but in a lot of situations, this would be a downside to using `//`.

Comment: But he said it did work.  I guess he could not be on apache and you both be right.

Comment: My setup does work, I'm using a catch-all rewrite: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]`, then using PHP to parse the url and figure out what to be loading

Comment: Maybe he is breaking apart the `REQUEST_URI` to separate the parameters out then

Comment: A brilliant insight.  Makes good sense though.  PHP doesn't care what apache thinks about double slashes.

Comment: Yep, I'm using PHP to explode the URL by `'/'`, `$segment[0]` is the controller to load, `segment[1]` is the method/action (and `if ($segment[1] == '') $segment[1] = 'index';`, and all following segments are used as parameters for the method. So `/blog//first-post` would essentially run `$framework->blog->index('first-post')` and `/blog/first-post` would run `$framework->blog->first-post()` which wouldn't exactly work ;)