# Double slash in URL path - bad practice?

Tags: url, seo, slash, google-index

My web app generates multiple slashes in URLs like: http://www.example.com/some///slashes.

Is it a bad practice? Does Google care?

Does Google see `/some/slashes` and `/some///slashes` as different URLs? If it does, I think Google won't merge PageRank of these URLs, or will it?

Thanks!

Comment: You can check the site

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161177/url-with-multiple-forward-slashes-does-it-break-anything

Comment: Ok, so I get that Google see it as different URL's. So do you think Google considers both URLs the same and joins it's PageRanks? Or will it have some negative SEO effect?

Comment: @koubic, I know I am a late on the response, but please see my answer on the same link as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can lead to search engines indexing incorrect URLs and duplicate content. Multiple pages with the same content is bad for SEO. Duplicated pages detract from the original page. You can end up with the incorrect URL being indexed and the proper URL being removed from search results.