# Is a single slash the same as double slash after the domain name?

Tags: url, seo, slash

See, what happens in most cases is, if we try to open forcefully this url: **www.example.com/games**

as **www.example.com//games** - it automatically gets redirected to **www.example.com/games** - this only.

But, what when we are able to see both urls in the browser, I mean **www.example.com/games** is loaded correctly and **www.example.com//games** is getting loaded correctly, no redirection takes place?

Is it a bad sign?

or bad for SEO or

Search Engine take them as two urls?

Please, try to include link to reliable sources if possible.

Comment: This is a colon: `:`. This is a Bar, or pipe: `|`. This is a slash: `/`. You have referred to all 3.

Comment: Yes, i meant slash.

Please, add your views now.

Comment: Please, add your views.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [url with multiple forward slashes, does it break anything?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161177/url-with-multiple-forward-slashes-does-it-break-anything)

Comment: And of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256190/are-there-any-downsides-to-using-double-slashes-in-urls

Answer (score 0):

Sunny,

This is a bad sign in terms of domain names and seo filed too. Double slash cannot crawl by the bot as per the W3c.

it would be prefer if you stuck with single slash.